# Scikit-learn : Cross validation and Confidence Intervals

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to calculate the confidence interval for my classification model using DecisionTreeClassifier in scikit-learn.

Reading the scikit-learn documentation about cross validation and confidence intervals (https://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/cross_validation.html) I found the code below and it seemed pretty straight forward; however, I don't understand why the upper limit is greater than 1, how can the accuracy be higher than 100%?

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1)
scores = cross_val_score(clf, iris.data, iris.target, cv=5)
print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores.mean(), scores.std() * 2))
Accuracy: 0.98 (+/- 0.03)
```

Comment: The problem is in assumption that accuracy is normally distributed. I guess that could be an omission in scikit-learn documentation. Check https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/194141/can-a-confidence-interval-be-greater-than-1

Answer (score 2):

It cannot be larger than 1 obviously.

The underlying assumption in this code is that the scores computed in `scores` are distributed according to the Normal Distribution. Then the 95% confidence interval is given by `mean+/- 2*std`.

It gives sensible results most of the time, but in your case, it is just ill-defined because the mean accuracy is already so close to 1. I know this is not a great solution, but maybe you can reduce your confidence interval to 68%? Then you would just need to remove the factor 2 in front of the `std`, and the upper bound would be 99.5%.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I’d like to clarify this is not my code but it’s taken from the scikit-learn documentation about cross-validation, which is what confused me and made me think that maybe it was okay to obtain an upper bound greater than 1. As you said, however,  it shouldn’t be the case. Using a lower confidence interval might be a good idea !

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/report-classifier-performance-confidence-intervals/), it may be a better idea to just clip the confidence interval.